# Unable to load dynamic library php_zmq.dll - The specified module could not be found

Tags: xampp, zeromq, php-extension, failed-installation, php-7.1

I have **XAMPP** with PHP Version
**PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Jan  3 2018 20:16:04) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )**.

I want to install the ZeroMQ extension, which

- I downloaded from here http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows specifically **7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x86**
- moved the `php_zmq.dll` to the file `C:\xampp\php\ext`, and
- wrote **`extension=php_zmq.dll`** into the file **`C:\xampp\php\php.ini`**,
- wrote **`C:\xampp\php\ext`** in to Windows **`PATH`**,

but I still getting this error :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.  in Unknown on line 0

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the solution - the **`libzmq.dll`** file must be copied / moved to a directory, where the **`php.exe`** file is.

So in my case to **`C:\xampp\php`**

Answer (score 3):

I did the same as others suggested, but it still did not work. Then I noticed that there is one more .DLL file in the ZMQ ZIP file: libsodium.dll. When I copied this to the C:\xampp\php directory, it worked.

To summarize: files `libsodium.dll` and `libzmq.dll` must be copied to `C:\xampp\php` directory.