# How to add ZeroMQ extension in PHP IIS

Tags: php, iis, zeromq, php-7.2

This question is very similar to: [Unable to load dynamic library php_zmq.dll - The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031814/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-zmq-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-f?rq=1)

But I need an answer specific to configuration in IIS PHP Fast-CGI, may even be limited to v10 (Windows Server 2016). For me, the usual configuration works fine with XAMPP and Windows 10 but fails with IIS.

Here is what I have done till now:

1. Installed all available VC++ Redistributables
2. Installed ZeroMQ v4.0.4
3. Downloaded PHP ZMQ v1.1.3-7.2-ts-vc15-x64
4. Moved the php_zmq.dll to C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v7.2\ext
5. Moved libzmq.dll to C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v7.2
6. Added extension directive in php.ini
7. Added path to ext folder

Upon server restart, the following warning is thrown:

```
[01-Dec-2018 01:11:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zmq.dll' (tried: C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.2\ext\php_php_zmq.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

With `php -m`, I am also not able to see the zmq module listed.

Comment: When you run `php -m`, are you sure you are launching the 64 bit build?

Comment: @LexLi Yes, only 64-bit build is installed

Comment: Please run a tool like Process Monitor to check how PHP process locates the library. That might explain why the warning comes.

Answer (score 0):

you have this error :
php_php_zmq.dll.dll
and
you can change that file name from php_php_zmq.dll to php_php_zmq.dll.dll.